# Get column header text in printWhenExpression

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm new to *JasperReports* and I need a help.

We have a scenario in which the column header and the data are fetched dynamically. This is like a common component which will generate the report irrespective of the number of columns and the column headers and data (which are dynamic). The data (the columns and the data) are set to the report dynamically in the *Java* side with the *JasperReports API* and we just have a template as below in the *jrxml* file.

```xml
<jr:column width="92">
    <jr:columnHeader style="table 2_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="92" height="25" backcolor="#99CCFF"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[DYNAMIC_DATA_FIELD]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:columnHeader>
    <jr:detailCell style="table 2_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="92" height="25"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYNAMIC_DATA_FIELD}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
```

This template will be fetched in the *Java* side and the value for **DYNAMIC_DATA_FIELD** in the template will be replaced with the column header text and the data index depending in the result of a query.

Now I need to hide and show a few columns based on the selection of radio button in the UI. For this I'm planning to use the *`printWhenExpression`* but not sure how to get the column header text. I saw something like *`$P{JASPER_REPORT}.getColumnHeader()`* but not sure how to use it. So here is the condition which I'm trying to use (below is just a template and I'm not sure of the right syntax)...

```java
if (radioSelection == something) {
    if (columnHeaderText.endsWith('something') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please note that I will not be able to use this condition in the *Java* code as its a common component and all the reports use this. Since every report has a *jrxml* file in our scenario and this occurs only for a specific report, I'm trying to place the condition in the *jrxml* file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make boolean[] array with values to every column (display or not) ?
In this case you cat pass it's array into report.jrxml as parameter ($P{displayCols} for example).

In table set "Column print when" expression as $P{displayCols[number_of_column]}
Where number of column is concret digit (1 or 2 or 3 ...)

But in this case you must change "generation" jrxml? And column header text is not need in this case